# Unable to chdir to vpopmail/domains/domain directory vqadmin

Tags: centos6.6

I try to install qmail on CentOS 6.6 x86 using tutorial from http://qmr.madkom.pl/.
I did it before with success on centos 5.10 and fedora (following www.qmailroks.org witch is not longer available) both servers run like a charm for years with multiple domains.

After struggle with daemon tools I run into other problem with vqadmin.
web interface work, I can authenticate but when I try to add a domain I get this:

```
 Unable to chdir to vpopmail/domains/domain directory


 VqAdmin Main Menu
 user: admin
 permission: senior
```

and is not creating domain directory in /etc/vpopmail/domains/
If I use command line I can add domain (/home/vpopmail/domains/domain.ro) but still not able to list it or add email account.

I get this error:

"All domains

List Domains: could not open assign file"

I try to run: `/downloads/qmailrocks/scripts/util/qmr_inst_check`

and I get a very strange error:

```
[root@mail /]# /downloads/qmailrocks/scripts/util/qmr_inst_check
! /var/log/qmail has wrong mode, should be 750
...try: chmod 750 /var/log/qmail
! /var/log/qmail/qmail-smtpd has wrong mode, should be 750
...try: chmod 750 /var/log/qmail/qmail-smtpd
! /var/log/qmail/qmail-pop3d has wrong mode, should be 750
...try: chmod 750 /var/log/qmail/qmail-pop3d
! /var/log/qmail/qmail-send has wrong mode, should be 750
...try: chmod 750 /var/log/qmail/qmail-send
```

But /var/log/qmail is 0750
and all are 0750

```
[root@mail log]# ls -l

...
drwxr-x---. 5 qmaill root     4096 Feb  6 18:58 qmail
...

[root@mail log]# ls -l qmail
total 12
drwxr-x---. 2 qmaill root 4096 Feb 16 07:48 qmail-pop3d
drwxr-x---. 2 qmaill root 4096 Feb 16 07:48 qmail-send
drwxr-x---. 2 qmaill root 4096 Feb 16 07:48 qmail-smtpd
```

Can anyone help me fix vqadmin?

Comment: A common problem with third-party software on RHEL and CentOS is SELinux denials. `getenforce` will display SELinux status and if in Enforcing mode a temporary change with `setenforce Permissive` is a quick and dirty method to test if your issues are indeed SELinux related.

Comment: Thanke you very much! you are right! I set SELinux and everything works! vqadmin is ok now.

Comment: Typically you should get your software to work *with* SELinux rather than disabling it :-) But if you decide to do the latter, please remember that `setenforce Permissive` is **not** persistent...